# NHibernate Evict throws an Object reference not set to an instance of an object error

Tags: c#, nhibernate

When I:

```
if (nhsession.Contains(myobj))
    nhsesion.Evict(myobj)
```

At the `Evict` method call I get this error:

```
{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}     ????????
```

With this stacktrace:

```
at NHibernate.Event.Default.EvictVisitor.EvictCollection(IPersistentCollection collection)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.EvictVisitor.EvictCollection(Object value, CollectionType type)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.EvictVisitor.ProcessCollection(Object collection, CollectionType type)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractVisitor.ProcessValue(Object value, IType type)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractVisitor.ProcessValue(Int32 i, Object[] values, IType[] types)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractVisitor.ProcessEntityPropertyValues(Object[] values, IType[] types)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractVisitor.Process(Object obj, IEntityPersister persister)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultEvictEventListener.DoEvict(Object obj, EntityKey key, IEntityPersister persister, IEventSource session)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultEvictEventListener.OnEvict(EvictEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireEvict(EvictEvent evictEvent)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Evict(Object obj)
   at NewCash.UI.Presenters.OperazioneIRSPresenter.UserAction(String Action) in C:\AkrosProduzione\NewCash4\src_4\NewCash.UI\Presenters\OperazionePresenter\OperazioneIRSPresenter.vb:line 230
```

It seems that `NHibernate evict` tries to evict a null collection, how can I avoid this without having to initialize all collections properties of the object? Or is there a problem that I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: This sounds like a bug, have you looked on the Jira https://nhibernate.jira.com/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?

Comment: @Rippo, thanx for your risponse, i can see a similar bug, but seems not the same https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1180

Comment: @Krzysztof Koźmic , maybe, do you have some idea for this issue, thank you.

Comment: even if it is a bug it is good practice to initialize collection properties to empty collections

Comment: @Firo unfortunately this is a big application that we're migrwting and it's hard to check one by one the inizialization of the collections not loaded by nhibernate, thanx.

Comment: i would initialize the collections in the Constructor of the Model classes. thats where they belong.

Comment: @Firo, can you please write your comment as an answer to mark it as answered?, thax.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a bug as Rippo linked.

however even if it is a bug it is good practice to initialize collection properties to empty collections in the constructor of the model classes. Then it is not nessessary to check for null collection each time on access and to change the collection type (e.g. decorating it) there is only one place to change it.